# Entity framework map entity to multiple tables?

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I'm facing a problem using EF. I have the following situation:

> Table User: Username, Password, RoleId, IsActive, CreatedDate, ActivedDate
>
> Table Admin: Username, Name
>
> Table Staff: Username, Name, Position, Phone

From this database schema i'd like to generate the following entity by merge tables data:

```
public class User
{
    [Key]
    public string Username { get; set; }
    public string Password { get; set; }
    public int RoleId { get; set; }
    public bool IsActive { get; set; }
    public DateTime CreatedDate { get; set; }
    public DateTime ActivedDate { get; set; }

    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Phone { get; set; }
    public string Position { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("RoleId")]
    public Role Role { get; set; }
}
```

configuration class:

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        modelBuilder.Entity<User>()
            .Map(map =>
            {
                map.Properties(p => new
                {
                    p.Username,
                    p.Password,
                    p.RoleId,
                    p.IsActive,
                    p.CreatedDate,
                    p.ActivedDate
                });
                map.ToTable("User");
            })
            .Map(map =>
            {
                map.Properties(p => new
                {
                    p.Username,
                    p.Name
                });
                map.ToTable("Admin");
            }).Map(map =>
            {
                map.Properties(p => new
                {
                    p.Username,
                    p.Name,
                    p.Phone,
                    p.Position
                });
                map.ToTable("Staff");
            });

        base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);
    }
```

I've tested it but it doesn't work as expected. I always get this message:

> Properties for type 'User' can only be mapped once. The non-key property 'Name' is mapped more than once. Ensure the Properties method specifies each non-key property only once.

Am I missing something?

Comment: maybe someone has an actual solution - but I *think* you'll have to go the same road you went with `Role` (foreign-key, ...)

Comment: Are the users inherited users of a User class? Or does your code only have a single User for all those entities? You can lookup inheritance strategies here: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/alexj/archive/2009/04/15/tip-12-choosing-an-inheritance-strategy.aspx I see that you have a role entity, I don't think that how I would have solved it... I would have a base Person, and let the User, Admin and Staff inheritate from that abstract class. And then I would have used Table Per Type (TPT) to avoid several null values in my database.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that the two `Name`s in `Admin` and `Staff` of course can't both be mapped onto one `Name` property in `User`.

But you can have two different name properties and map both to the same column names in two tables:

Changes in `User`:

```
public class User
{
    [Key]
    public string Username { get; set; }
    ...
    public string AdminName { get; set; }
    public string StaffName { get; set; }
    ...
}
```

And the mapping fragments:

```
.Map(map =>
{
    map.Properties(p => new
    {
        p.Username,
        p.AdminName
    });
    map.Property(p => p.AdminName).HasColumnName("Name");
    map.ToTable("Admin");
}).Map(map =>
{
    map.Properties(p => new
    {
        p.Username,
        p.StaffName,
        p.Phone,
        p.Position
    });
    map.Property(p => p.StaffName).HasColumnName("Name");
    map.ToTable("Staff");
});
```